# Vimscript remove control characters

Tags: vim

I have a vimscript function shown below that performs a search and replace on the currently yanked/copied text buffer and pastes them into a file.

```
function Repaste(s, ...)
  for i in a:000
    let sub = substitute(getreg('"'), a:s, i, 'ge')
    let sane = substitute(sub, '[^[:print:]]', '\n', 'ge')
    call append(line('.'), sane)
  endfor
endfunction

command -nargs=* RP call Repaste(<f-args>)
```

When I call this function I get `^@` characters in place of new lines.
Here is an example of the yanked/copied text

`set cindent`

Here is an example of the command executed

```
:RP c d e f
```

Here is the output

```
set findent ^@  
set eindent ^@ 
set dindent ^@
```

How do i remove these characters and why do they appear? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should be using `'\r'` instead of `'\n'`

Comment: `\r` gives me `^M` .

Comment: Hmm.  What about `<CR>`?

Comment: Prints `<CR>` instead of `^@`

Comment: If I remove the call to `append` and do this `put=sub` it works

Comment: Excellent. Write up an answer with the solution and mark it solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `append()` function is a low-level one. [`:help append()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#append%28%29) shows that the `{expr}` as a *String* type is inserted *as one text line*, regardless of newlines in its content. The `^@` is the representation of `\n` inside a line; cp `:help <Nul>`.

If you really want to keep using `append()`, you have to provide a *List* type; to obtain this, you can `split()` your String:

```
call append(line('.'), split(sane, '\n'))
```

However, I think you're better off by using a higher-level function to insert the created lines, using `:put` with the *expression register* to insert the contents of your variable:

```
put =sane
```

This will:

- automatically handle embedded newlines
- set the change marks `'[` and `']` to the inserted text
- print a message `4 more lines` (if the inserted number exceeds the `'report'` threshold).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the call to `append` with `put=sub` produces the required result.